# making list in python

Tags: python, list

When i executed the following python script

```
list= (1,2,3,4,1,2,7,8)

for number in list:
    item1= number
    item2= list[list.index(item1)+2]
    couple= item1, item2
    print couple
```

the goal is to link each number with the second following
I obtain this result

```
(1, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 1)
(4, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 4)
```

(and then the index gets out of range but this is not the problem)

My question is why the number 1 in the fifth line is still coupled to the number 3 and how can i make that it is coupled to the number 7; idem for the number 2 in the sixth line that should be coupled to the number 8.

additional question
what do I do if i only want to make a list of the couples that start with 1:  [(1,3), (1,7)]

Comment: Please don't use the builtin `list` as a variable name!

Comment: That's not a list. A list is defined with brackets, []

    abc = [1,2,3,4,1,2,7,8]

Answer (score 3):

list.index returns the offset of the **first** occurrence of the value in the list - thus if you do [1,1,1].index(1), the answer will always be 0, even though 1 and 2 are also valid answers.

Instead, try:

```
from itertools import islice, izip, ifilter

mylist = [1,2,3,4,1,2,7,8]
for pair in ifilter(lambda x: x[0]==1, izip(mylist, islice(mylist, 2, None))):
    print pair
```

results in

```
(1, 3)
(1, 7)
```

Comment: Note that you can write islice(mylist, 2, None).

Comment: If you're using islice why you not use izip?

Comment: what do I do if i only want to make a list of the couples that start with 1:  [(1,3), (1,7)]

Comment: @Preys: have updated answer to include filtering on first item's value

Comment: can I use the same for a list of words for example myslist

Comment: @Preys: sure; just change the filter lambda, ie lambda x: x[0]=='the'

Comment: can I use the same for a list of words for example mylist=['book', 'ring', 'finger', 'bottle', 'lamp', 'computer', 'book', 'world', 'paper'] and I want every couple of which the first letter of the first word is a 'b'; so this would give ('book', 'finger'), ('bottle', 'computer'), ('book','paper').

Comment: @Preys: lambda x: x[0][:1].lower()=='b'

Answer (score 1):

`xs.index(x)` gives you the index of the first occurence of `x` in `xs`. So when you get to the second `1`, `.index` gives you the index of the first `1`.

If you need the index alongside the value, use `enumerate`: `for i, number in enumerate(numbers): print number, numbers[i+2]`.

Note that I deliberately didn't use the name `list`. It's the name of a built-in, you shouldn't overwrite it. Also note that `(..., ...)` is a *tuple* (and therefore can't be changed), not a list (which is defined in square brackets `[..., ...]` and can be changed).

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicates in the list so index always returns the first index.

Start your program with `for index in range(len(list) - 1)`

Comment: (1) `-1` is wrong if you want all numbers from `0` to `len(list)` (`range` already is a half-open range) and you'd need `-2` if you wanted to prevent out of bounds errors (which are not the topic of the question). (2) Use `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.index` which returns the first occurrence of `number`.

consider:

```
for number in range(len(list)):
    item1= list[number]
    item2= list[number+2]
    couple= item1, item2
    print couple
```

Comment: This results in an IndexError when number+2 goes off the end of the list.

Comment: what do I do if i only want to make a list of the couples that start with 1:  [(1,3), (1,7)]

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> zip(lst, lst[2:])
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 2), (1, 7), (2, 8)]
```

To get only pairs (1, X):

```
>>> [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(lst, lst[2:]) if a == 1]
[(1, 3), (1, 7)]
```

Recommended reading:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html

Comment: what do I do if i only want to make a list of the couples that start with 1:  [(1,3), (1,7)]

Comment: @Preys: [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(lst, lst[2:]) if a == 1]